# Обновление данных ListView при подключении к сети WiFi Android

Tags: android, android-studio, wifi, adapter

Написал приложение для получения курса валют с сайта РБК. Все работает кроме обновления данных через адаптер в listView. Когда запускаю приложение с включенным Wi-Fi, актуальные данные выводятся на экран. Если же WiFi отключить, запустить приложение, соответственно ListView будет пустым, но при подключении WiFi, список так и не обновляется. Буду рад любой помощи. Заранее спасибо. Приведу частичный код:

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Адаптер:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context ctx;
private ArrayList<CurrencyRateModel> arrayList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<CurrencyRateModel> arrayList) {

    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    inflater = ((Activity)ctx).getLayoutInflater();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //TextView tv = (TextView)convertView;

    // For debug
   /* if(convertView == null) {

        tv = new TextView(ctx);

    }
    tv.setText("позиция =" + position);*/
    ViewHolder vh;
    if(convertView == null) {

        vh = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_get_currency_rates, null);
        vh.tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        vh.tvDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        vh.tvConvertedData = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.converted);
        convertView.setTag(vh);
    }
    else {

        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    CurrencyRateModel item = arrayList.get(position);

    vh.tvTitle.setText(item.getName()+" - "+item.getCharCode());
    vh.tvDescription.setText("Курс сегодня: "+ String.format("%.2f Р", item.getValue())
            + " Предыдущий: " + String.format("%.2f Р",item.getPrevious()));
    vh.tvConvertedData.setText("Конвертированные данные: "
            + String.format("%.2f Р", item.getRate()));

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView tvTitle, tvDescription, tvConvertedData;
}}
```

Мейн:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Get data from RBC https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js
// Currency data

private ArrayList<CurrencyRateModel> listOfCurrency;
private CustomAdapter myAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // async TASK Run

    registerReceiver(new WifiReceiver(), new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
    GetRbcExchangeRates async = new GetRbcExchangeRates();
    async.execute();
}


ICustomCallback myCallback = new ICustomCallback() {

    @Override
    public void resultValue(double value) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "value: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        for(int i = 0, size = listOfCurrency.size(); i < size; i++) {

            CurrencyRateModel item = listOfCurrency.get(i);
            item.setRate(item.getValue() * value / item.getNominal());
        }
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //myAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(); Мгновенное обновление;
    }
};

private class GetRbcExchangeRates extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // private ArrayList<CurrencyRateModel> listOfCurrency = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        StringBuilder jSonResult = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                jSonResult.append(line);

            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            publishProgress("MESSAGE", "Отсутствует подключение к интернет!");
        }
        finally {

            if(connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();

            try {
                if(bufferedReader !=null)
                    bufferedReader.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        listOfCurrency = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            JSONObject rbcGETRates = new JSONObject(jSonResult.toString());
            JSONObject jSonValute = rbcGETRates.getJSONObject("Valute");
            Iterator<String> arrayKey = jSonValute.keys();

            while(arrayKey.hasNext()) {

                String key = arrayKey.next();
                JSONObject jSonItem = jSonValute.getJSONObject(key);
                CurrencyRateModel currencyitems = new CurrencyRateModel();
                currencyitems.setId(jSonItem.getString("ID"));
                currencyitems.setNameCode(jSonItem.getString("NumCode"));
                currencyitems.setCharCode(jSonItem.getString("CharCode"));
                currencyitems.setNominal(jSonItem.getInt("Nominal"));
                currencyitems.setName(jSonItem.getString("Name"));
                currencyitems.setValue(jSonItem.getDouble("Value"));
                currencyitems.setPrevious(jSonItem.getDouble("Previous"));
                listOfCurrency.add(currencyitems);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if(values[0].equals("MESSAGE")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, values[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        super.onPostExecute(s);

        ListView lsView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.currencyView);
        myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, listOfCurrency);
        lsView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        lsView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                FragmentManager fgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                ValueInputDialog dialog = new ValueInputDialog();

                dialog.inputValueDialogInit(myCallback);
                dialog.show(fgManager, "");
            }
        });
    }
}

public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NetworkInfo netInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
            Log.d("WifiReceiver", "Have Wifi Connection");

        if(listOfCurrency == null && listOfCurrency.size() == 0) {

            GetRbcExchangeRates getRbcExchangeRates = new GetRbcExchangeRates();
            getRbcExchangeRates.execute();
        }

        else

            Log.d("WifiReceiver", "Don't have Wifi Connection");
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем удалось это реализовать. Для начала изменил манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```
 public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        boolean isConnected = wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting() ||
                mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected) {
            // Тут и запускаю Async c обновлением списка
            GetRbcExchangeRates async = new GetRbcExchangeRates();
            async.execute();
            Toast.makeText(context, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "YES");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "NO");
        }
    }
}
```

В MainActivity регистрирую событие:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    registerReceiver(new NetworkChangeReceiver(), new 
    IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

}
```

Теперь, если запустить приложение при выключенном WiFi, а после включить. Список обновиться автоматически.